# Error on exporting an Eclipse-RCP application:The import org.osgi.service.component cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I want to export the product of my Eclipse-RCP application. One of the plug-ins in the product contains some osgi services. When I export the Product, a logs.zip folder is generated which contains the following log: **The import org.osgi.service.component cannot be resolved** .

I think the reason is, that in the plug-in that uses the osgi services the jar which contains the package **org.osgi.service.component**. This is imported in the plug-in dependencies (the other dependencies in this folder are plug-ins). But I can't remove the jar from the plug-in deppendencies.

When I want to start the application in Eclipse everything works fine and it runs.

Comment: Your xxx.product file used by the export must list all the required plug-ins (or features). This file isn't used when you run from within Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My plug-in has the exact same dependencies a my application in eclipse. The missing package is in none of those listed as a required package. It's imported as the jar in the dependencies, not as a plug-in.

Comment: Imports still have to come from a plug-in. This one is probably the `org.eclipse.osgi.services` plug-in

Comment: Which IDE version you are using and are you building an Eclipse4 application?

Comment: I'm using Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0). And I am building an e4 application.